# Make inputs dynamically with values from an array

Tags: php

I want to make inputs dynamically with values that correspond to the second array values.

the code:

```
$first = array('location', 'genre', 'studio', 'Lord_Of_the_Rings');
$second = array(
    'location' => 1, 
    'genre' => 2, 
    'studio' => 3, 
    'Lord_Of_the_Rings' => 4
);


$intersect = array_intersect($first, array_keys($second));
foreach($intersect as $key) {
    $t =  $second[$key];
}

foreach ($first as $the_tax) {

    $do_val = $the_tax.'-no-';

    echo "<p>$the_tax <input type=\"text\" name=\"{$do_val}\" value=\"$t\" /></p>";
}
```

This outputs:

```
<p>location <input type="text" value="4" name="location-no-"></p>
<p>genre <input type="text" value="4" name="genre-no-"></p>
<p>studio <input type="text" value="4" name="studio-no-"></p>
<p>Lord_Of_the_Rings <input type="text" value="4" name="Lord_Of_the_Rings-no-"></p>
```

AS you can see, each input has a value of 4.
In this particular case, the values in the inputs should be `1` for the first, `2` for the second, `3` for the third and `4` for the fourth one, but I can't achieve that.

Comment: You should consider using one array instead of two like `$form = array('location' => array('value' => '1'));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting up $t in a foreach, but when it gets to the next loop, it is only going to have the last value.

Could you not just do:

```
$first = array('location', 'genre', 'studio', 'Lord_Of_the_Rings');
$second = array(
    'location' => 1, 
    'genre' => 2, 
    'studio' => 3, 
    'Lord_Of_the_Rings' => 4
);


foreach ($first as $the_tax) {

    $do_val = $the_tax.'-no-';

    echo "<p>$the_tax <input type=\"text\" name=\"{$do_val}\" value=\"{$second[$the_tax]}\" /></p>";
}
```

Comment: Yea! Though $first should be $second. NICE ONE!